# Screen is not working please help ;-;

Tags: screen

[image: What My new screen does...]

So a week ago i purchased a 7" MAKIBES touchscreen for my raspberry pi 2

I went on this website for help with setting this screen up:
http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/7inch_HDMI_LCD_(B)#Rev1.1_LCD_Images_for_Raspberry_Pi

Unfortunately the screen didn't work. I plug the pi into my normal monitor to fiddle with the config and install what i think are the right drivers but it still isn't working. Some people on the Amazon reviews said that the issue could be NOOBS but I don't know about that. I don't really need the touchscreen part of the screen so if its an issue with that and a solution is available that means i get no touch screen I don't mind. I wanted to prove to my family that computers can be fun and I can build my own tiny computer but in the process have made myself look like an idiot. Please help me ;-;
**Thanks**

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Is there any output at all? Does the backlight turn on? How is it being powered?

Comment: The Screen just outouts the above, it is getting power via the micro usb. The backlight does turn on. it flickers turns off every few seconds.

Comment: What's the rating on the power supply?

Comment: just to clarify, i'm an idiot xD The plug that goes into the pi says: 100 - 240 volts 0.5A 50-60Hz and 24-32VA. Also Output - 5V 2.0A MAX

Comment: That is nowhere near enough power to run both the screen and the RPi. You should be using a more powerful charger for the RPi alone. I would suggest a 2A charger. Ideally, the screen would be on its own power supply

Comment: There isn't a slot to power the screen on its own but I get what you mean, is there a suitable charger on Amazon for my pi? Will any micro usb charger do?

Comment: response posted as an actual answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Based on everything you've described in the comments, it sounds like your issue is directly related to your power supply. The Raspberry Pi Foundation [recommends](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs) a minimum of a `1.8`. According to your comment, you have a `.5 A`.

> .., is there a suitable charger on Amazon for my pi? Will any micro usb charger do?

That is actually one of the best parts about the USB standard. USB stands for *Universal Serial Bus*; what works for one, should work for any. I have two of [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00M26DQBK) and have been very happy with them. But again, anything with the proper power output will work.

Comment: may look like an idiot saying this but just to be safe, would this one be good enough http://www.amazon.co.uk/Belkin-MixIt-Colour-Range-Charger/dp/B009S67LF4/ref=sr_1_10?ie=UTF8&qid=1457120044&sr=8-10&keywords=2.1+AMP+micro+usb+charger

Comment: @TheDizzeePiggeh: that should work fine. I would recommend getting the cable with it (Amazon recommends one) the one that came with your .5 may be in the thin side.

Comment: The 0.5A is 240V. The output is 5V 2A. This is unlikely to be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to set up the touchscreen and power supply via your raspberry pi USB. Worked a treat on a variety of distros for me.

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-5-800x480-tft-hdmi-monitor-touchscreen-backpack/raspberry-pi-config

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.